# If $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space, then $(X\setminus\{0\}, d)$ is a metric space for $d(x, y) = \frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|+\|y\|}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the following statement: If $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space, then $(X\setminus\{0\}, d)$ is a metric space for $$d(x, y) = \frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|+\|y\|}$$ I'm trying to figure out whether this statement is true (and if it is, whether it's only true in a special setting, e.g. uniformly convex Banach spaces). The context is that I'm trying to define a "similarity metric" between two vectors in a general normed vector space with the invariance $d(x, y) = d(\alpha x, \alpha y)$ for $\alpha\neq 0$, among some other properties. It seems like it could maybe be a textbook problem, but I'm not quite sure if I've seen it somewhere or not. It's pretty clear that $d(x, y) = 0$ implies $x = y$ and $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$, but the triangle inequality is a bit sticky. We can rearrange $d(x, y)\leq d(x, z)+d(z, y)$ as $$\|x-y\|\leq \left(\frac{\|x-z\|}{\|x\|+\|z\|}+\frac{\|y-z\|}{\|y\|+\|z\|}\right)(\|x\|+\|y\|)$$ which feels stronger than the standard triangle inequality on $(X, \|\cdot\|)$. Does anybody have some insights on this? Am I missing a standard trick here? Thanks!

Comment: How is $d(0,0)$ defined?

Comment: Good point. I'll revise the question to consider $(X\setminus\{0\}, d)$.

Comment: Some compelling evidence: The set of vectors $x = (1,0), y = (r, 0), z = (0,1)$ satisfies the triangle inequality for all $r$ with your metric.

Comment: The counterexample $x=(-1, -1)$, $y=(2, 0)$, $z=(0, -2)$ with the max-norm on $\Bbb R^2$ from [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798102/if-d-is-a-metric-is-dx-y-1dx-0dy-0-a-metric#comment1657387_801743) to a similar problem is a counterexample for your metric as well: $d(x, y) = 1 > d(x, z)+d(z, y) = 1/2+1/3$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample! I'm still trying to prove it or find a counterexample for uniformly convex $(X, \|\cdot\|)$, if you have any insights in that particular case.

Comment: @MichaelL. I think the counterexample exhibited by Martin R would still work if $\mathbb R^2$ were endowed with the $\ell^p$-norm for $p$ large enough. And $(\mathbb R^2,\|\cdot\|_p)$ is uniformly convex for any $p\in(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @triple_sec: $p \ge 5$ is sufficient, by numerical calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the special case of $X=\mathbb R$. Then, $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{|x|+|y|}$ is not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Along $x=y,\ (x,y)\to (0,0)\Rightarrow d(x,y)\to 0$ whereas along $x=0$ we have $d(x,y)\to 1.$ So even if we define $d(0,0)=0$ the triangle inequality can not be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I revised the question earlier to consider $(X\setminus \{0\}, d)$ to resolve this inconsistency. Does your answer still hold in that case?